# git push not adding any code to remote repository on linux

Tags: git

I am running a git server on my raspberry pi and I have been trying to push my code to a remote repository located on the pi at /var/www/project. However, no code has been added to the remote repository, despite the output of git push showing that 13.40MB has been pushed.

```
user@user ~/git_projects/project $ git push origin master

Counting objects: 2526, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2519/2519), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2526/2526), 13.40 MiB | 818 KiB/s, done.
Total 2526 (delta 723), reused 0 (delta 0)
To /var/www/project
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

I did the following to setup the remote repository:

```
cd /var/www/project
git init --bare
```

and in my source code folder:

```
cd ~/git_projects/project
git init
git remote add origin /var/www/project
git add .
git commit -m "test"
```

Comment: Did you run `git remote add origin /var/www/project` on your computer ? If yes, it is normal it didn't work.

Comment: Yes I did. Is there another way to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

The problem:

By doing `git remote add origin /var/www/project`, you are saying that the remote repository is the location `/var/www/project` of your computer, but not of your raspberry pi. So `git push` pushes your work to your computer, at another place.

You need to set your raspberry as the remote, using its IP address. A walkthrough is detailed [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server), but you can find many other tutorials on the web.